# Running Time and Big Oh

Tags: python-3.x, time, time-complexity, big-o

How can I write an algorithm to make sure it satisfies a specific running time? 
I understand how linear and quadratic running times works but I am having difficulty with O(logn) or O(nlogn)

My first question is this:

I need to satisfy the nlogn running time by filling in the blanks:

```
i = n*n*n*n*n
while (i > 1):
    j = 1
    while (j < n*n):
        k = j
        while (k > 0):
            k = _____
    j = _____
i = _____
```

I don't know how to tackle this question.

My second question is, how do you meticulously go through an algorithm and determine it's running time if it's not linear or quadratic?

Thank you

Comment: Binary search is the classic logn algorithm.  Also, `j` doesn't vary in your innermost `while` loop, so this will run forever.

Comment: I made a mistake, thank you for pointing it out. I fixed it.

Comment: The three loops are a little bit of misdirection.  You only need 2.  You want the innermost loop to execute `O(logn)` times, the second loop to execute `O(n)` times (or vice versa), and the outermost loop to execute only once (or some other constant factor)

Comment: This will still run forever: `i` and `j` should be incremented/decremented outside the loops that check their values.  Please indent your code properly as this changes the behavior of code in python.